# Chrome Bookmarks: How to replace part of url with language that is changing regarding the location

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a problem creating a function in JS as a bookmark in Chrome. I'm on a page that goes:

[www.example.com/us/en/xxx](http://www.example.com/us/en/xxx) but I want to change it by one click in JS so that the URL changes to:
[www.desiredpage.com/author/en/xxx](http://www.desiredpage.com/author/en/xxx)

The problem for me here is that the /us/ part is the part of string that changes regarding where user connects from. This part is always two-character, and this part of the url always needs to be changed to /author/. Can someone help me with this? :D

I've already tried using the replace function but in this case, where some part of the string is nonstatic my ideas just ended.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit late, but here is an answer.

if the /us/ is always right after the domain, then you can use a split method:

```
let arr = url.split('/')
arr[1] = 'author'
url = arr.join('/')
```

To put it into context:

```js
function run(){
div = document.getElementById('two')
url = document.getElementById('one').value
let arr = url.split('/')
// url like https://google.com/us/en/xxx
// turns into ['https:', '', 'google.com', 'us', 'en', 'xxx']
arr[3] = 'author'
arr[2] = 'newdomain.com'
url = arr.join('/')
div.innerHTML = url
}
```

```html
URL: <input id='one'><br>
<button onclick = 'run()'>Run</button><br>
<div id='two'></div>
```

now translating the snippet into a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:url = location.href; arr = url.split('/'); arr[3] = 'author'; arr[2] = 'newdomain.com'; url = arr.join('/'); location.href = url
```

change the newdomain.com into your desiered domain.